# How to use Python-gsmmodem module to send sms?

Tags: python, sms, gsm

I'm somewhat new to Python. I've installed pyserial & python-gsmmodem module. I can find some files including sendsms.py but I don't know how to use it to send sms. I've seen the examples folder but there's nothing I could find helpful. 
Should I make a new file and write something (what to write?) or do I have to use the sendsms.py file if I want to send sms? 
NOTE: I've run the sendsms.py file, it gives me error
**usage: scratch_2.py [-h] [-i PORT] [-b BAUDRATE] [-p PIN] [-d] DESTINATION
scratch_2.py: error: the following arguments are required: DESTINATION
Process finished with exit code 2**

not sure how to provide this argument

Comment: Seems like a command line tool example usage `python sendsms.py -i COM1 -b 9600 -p <your PIN> -d <mobile number> "my SMS text"`.

Comment: I've to integrate it with my larger application. How can I provide these arguments from my application(provide values in variables after taking input) Because it gives an error if i try to do that.
Here's the link to the 'python-gsmmodel' modlue it has sendsms.py file.
https://github.com/faucamp/python-gsmmodem/tree/master/tools

Comment: i've made it bold. this is the entire error text.(traceback)

Comment: This _Error Message_ **is not** from `python-gsmmodem/tree/master/tools/sendsms.py`! There is **no** `scratch_2.py`? Whatever you use this is **not** from your provided Link. Download [this=>](https://github.com/faucamp/python-gsmmodem/blob/master/tools/sendsms.py)